# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=9

Tags: java, android, file, listview, android-adapter

I am building a simple file explorer and showing files on **ListView** using **simple_list_item_1** and **onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)** this oncItemClick works fine for all all other folder clicks
but on clicking last two items my application crashing and getting the following error
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=9
please take a look at code whats wrong

```
public class UploadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ListView listView;
protected File[] files;
protected LinkedList<String> pathList;
protected String path="/sdcard";
protected final String generalPath="/sdcard";
protected Bundle bundle;
private View emtyFolder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);
    pathList=new LinkedList<>();
    bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.local_files_listView);
    emtyFolder=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.emty_folder,null);



    openPath(path);


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (files[position].isDirectory())
            {
                Log.e("Folder Name",files[position].getName());
                if(files[position].listFiles().length>0) {
                    for (int i=0; i<files[position].listFiles().length;i++){
                        Log.e("File ",files[i].getName());
                    }
                    String newpath = files[position].getName();
                    forwardPath(newpath);
                    openPath(path);
                }
                else {
                    emtyFolder();
                    String newpath = files[position].getName();
                    forwardPath(newpath);
                    listView.setEmptyView(emtyFolder);
                }

            }
            if (files[position].isFile()) {
                Log.e("Is a file","True");
                String host=bundle.get("host").toString();
                String user=bundle.get("user").toString();
                String password=bundle.get("password").toString();
                int port= Integer.parseInt(bundle.get("port").toString());
                String remote=bundle.get("remote").toString();
                Transaction transaction=new 
                Transaction(host,user,password,port,getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    Log.e("Upload","Starting");
                    boolean status=transaction.Upload(remote, new File(path + 
              "/" + files[position].getName()));
                    Log.e("Upload", String.valueOf(status));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

public void backWardPath() {
    if (!pathList.isEmpty()) {
        this.path = generalPath;
        pathList.removeLast();
        for (int i = 0; i < pathList.size(); i++) {
            this.path = this.path + pathList.get(i);
        }
    }

    openPath(path);
}

public void forwardPath(String newPath) {
        this.path = generalPath;

    pathList.add("/" + newPath);
    for (int i = 0; i < pathList.size(); i++) {
        this.path = this.path + pathList.get(i);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);
    Log.e("Path",path);
    backWardPath();

}


public void openPath(String path) {
    File file = new File(path);
    files = file.listFiles();
    ArrayAdapter<File> arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<File>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,files);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}


private void emtyFolder(){
    Toast.makeText(this,"Empty Folder",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O30rq.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K446s.jpg)

Comment: you are right i am getting the error what you have mentioned the link butt i am stuck in my code whats wrong i don't know

Comment: Whats the whole logcat of the error?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler tells you that you try to access to an index out of range of your array.

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=9

The length of your array is 2 and you try to access with a index of 9. Check the line that compiler tells you where the problem occur.

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
for (int i=0; i<files[position].listFiles().length;i++){
    Log.e("File ",files[i].getName());
}
```

looks very suspicious. There's absolutely no relation between the number of files in the directory indicated by `files[position]` and the number of files in `files`. Probably you need another array of `File` objects.